# Reinitialize Datatable - Angular 2

Tags: angular, datatables

I have a component in my angular 2 application which has a dropdown list and a datatable. Based on the name selected from the dropdown list, I want to display the details in the datatable.

HTML -

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectName">
    <option *ngFor="let name of nameList" value= {{name.firstName}} >
      {{name.firstName}}
    </option>
  </select>

  <button id="submitName" (click)="getData()">Go</button>
</div>

<table id="namesTable" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="retrievedNames">


      <tr *ngFor="let name of retrievedNames">
        <td>{{name.id}}</td>
        <td>{{name.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{name.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{name.middleName}}</td>
      </tr>


  </tbody>

</table>
```

Component.ts file -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-namedetails',
  templateUrl: './namedetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./namedetails.component.css']
})
export class NameDetails implements OnInit {

  private nameList: any;
  private selectedName:string;

  private retrievedNames: any;
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(private _http:Http, private networkservice : NetworkService,private router: Router) { 
      }

  ngOnInit() {  
      this.fetchFirstNames();
  }

  fetchFirstNames(){
      this.networkservice.getAllFirstNames()
          .subscribe(
              res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.nameList = res;
            }); 
  }

  fetchAllDetails(){
       this.networkservice.getAllNames(this.selectedName)
          .subscribe(
              res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.retrievedNames = res;
              this.dtTrigger.next();
            }); 
  }
  getData(){
      this.fetchAllDetails();
  }
}
```

Whenever I change the value in the dropdown list - I get an alert saying "Datatable warning: table id= namesTable - Cannot reinitialize DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3". I understand that reinitializing the datatable again and again is not allow.

So whenever an item is selected/changed in the dropdown, I want to destroy the old instance of the datatable and create/reinitialize a new one.

How do I do this in angular 2 ?

UPDATE - 
this [Link](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender) helped me get rid of the error but I ran into another problem which I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867345/rerendering-datatable-in-angular-2-dtinstance-then-error?noredirect=1#comment76714088_44867345)

Comment: where are you handling the change event??

Comment: i call fetchAllDetails() when the button is clicked. It make a call to the backend api.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the similar issue but I solved it by destroying the datatable in angular using following code

```
$('#DataTables').DataTable().destroy();
```

where DataTables is my table's id.
You can write that in fetchAllDetails().
Hope it will help the future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the reference of the `retrievedNames` object might not have been changed.
When `getData()` is called clear the variable and reload it as below,

```
getData(){
     this.retrievedNames = [];
     this.fetchAllDetails();
}
```

So by this data table will be removed and loaded again.

Comment: tried it .. but it didnt work ... i still get the warning alert with the same error. I think i need a way to call the datatable.destroy() method ... i just cant figure out how to call the api method